# on scroll load more p-tree nodes angular

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

We have large records that needs to be shown in  and hence I am trying to implement on scroll  append more data to . But , I am not able to reach the debugger in my directive. Can someone help me to trigger the scroll event on reaching bottom? is there any other way to capture scroll event on  so that I can improve the performance of my page?

explore.component.html

```
<div style="overflow: auto !important;height: 488px !important;" scrollTracker  (scrollingFinished)="onScrollingFinished()">
<p-tree [value]="files | filter:searchText" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedFiles"
(onNodeSelect)="nodeSelect($event)" (onNodeExpand)="expandNode($event)"  ></p-tree>
</div>
```

explore.component.ts:

```
@Output() scrollingFinished = new EventEmitter<void>();
 


onScrollingFinished() {
this.scrollingFinished.emit();
}
```

directive:

```
import { Directive, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
selector: '[scrollTracker]'
})
export class ScrollTrackerDirective {
@Output() scrollingFinished = new EventEmitter<void>();

emitted = false;

@HostListener("window:scroll", [])
onScroll(): void {
debugger;
if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight && !this.emitted) {
this.emitted = true;
this.scrollingFinished.emit();
} else if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) < document.body.offsetHeight) {
this.emitted = false;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should alway listen to the event on the element where the scroll event is been triggered.

In your case you should listen on scroll event on your scrollable div which is in your template the div where you have used your scrollTracker directive.

To do this you should replace `window:scroll` with scroll event on the target element which is the scrollable div in this case.
In your onScroll method

```
constructor(private element: ElementRef) {}

@HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
public onScroll(event) {
    let element = this.element.nativeElement;
    if (element.scrollTop + element.clientHeight + 50 > element.scrollHeight) {
        // reached the bottom 
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try p-tree virtual scrolling for large records

Comment: virtual scroll is only for child nodes is what I saw in docs

Comment: @Mehyar, very helpful.Is it also possible to captur scroll on <p-tree> component?